# SQL saving selection to new table

Tags: sql

| id1 | id2 | v1 | v2 | v3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | I1 | A | B | C |
| P1 | I2 | D | E | F |
| P2 | I1 | A | B | D |
| P3 | I1 | A | D | E |
| P2 | I2 | B | D | E |

I need all entries with an A:
`SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE v1 = 'A' OR v2 = 'A' OR v3 = 'A'`

| id1 | id2 | v1 | v2 | v3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | I1 | A | B | C |
| P2 | I1 | A | B | D |
| P3 | I1 | A | D | E |

But how can I store it?
`save as X`??

Comment: Tag your DBMS first of all please

Comment: "Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL." (see: [SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql)) ==> Please correct the tags!

Comment: Just prepend your current query with `CREATE TABLE x AS` and run the statement for most of the DBMS if I understand your issue well...

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

you can directly create new table and put the query as insert data.

Try this:

```
create table new_table SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE v1 = 'A' OR v2 = 'A' OR v3 = 'A'
```

Comment: We don't know the DBMS yet, and this can't work for every DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * into x FROM test_table WHERE v1 = 'A' OR v2 = 'A' OR v3 = 'A'
```